# laravel 404 abort how to do this

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404

My problem is that I can't write code, to work view 404... 
My adress site is f.e : http://hospital.com
My route are like this:

```
 Route::post('/panel/perscriptions/add','PrescriptionsController@addPrescription');
 Route::post('/panel/perscriptions/delete','PrescriptionsController@deletePerscription');
```

On handler I have code like this:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
    {
        return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

My adress site is for example : http://hospital.com
And ofcourse it works when I wrote in url word, that is not in my route like this: http://hospital.com/someWordWhichIsNotInRoutes

Then my 404 view works, but when i paste in url : http://hospital.com/panel/perscriptions/add
Then I have error:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

Of course user has to be login to add perscription but It doesn't matter when I paste this url... always I have error. There's not, when user just add perscipritpion, only when I paste this in url independently. 
And here is my Controller function:

```
public function deletePerscription(Request $request)
{

    $Id = $request->input('id');

    $deleteRow = Perscription::where('id', $Id)->delete();

    return redirect('/panel/visits')->with('info', 'deleted');;

}
```

I really stuck on this... :(

I can't secure my code.. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NotFoundHttpException` and `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` are different types of exceptions. In the first case when you try to access the URL `http://hospital.com/someWordWhichIsNotInRoutes`, it does not exist at all and throws `NotFoundHttpException` which will provide you the `404` page. But for the second case, the URL `http://hospital.com/panel/perscriptions/add` exists but it allows only POST requests. When you try to access it through the browser it sends a GET request instead of POST request. Since your route doesn't allow GET request for this route, it will throw `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` exception. You can get over this by adding one more condition as follows in the Handler class.

```
if($exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException)
{
    // do the redirect here
}
```

Don't forget to import the class `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;`